# D3.js: yAxis text bold and blur

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to plot a customized yAxis using D3.js. My ideal result should be like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8VTz/).

But I haven't found the way to export the SVG image together with CSS styles. So I would like to move the styles to the SVG elements:

```
var yNode = svg.append("g")
               .style("fill", "none")
               .style("stroke", "#000")
               .attr("transform", "translate(" + left + ",0)")
               .attr("class", "axis")
               .call(yAxis);
yNode.selectAll('text')
               .style('font-size', '11px')
               .style('font-family', 'Lucida Console');
```

The code is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8VTz/1/).

All the styles are the same. But somehow the yAxis label of the later one becomes blur and bold. How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8VTz/3/)

You selected the whole axis dom element and applied the fill: none and stroke: black to it. The axis contains both: the path and the text, and both are going to be affected by the stroke. That's why your text is stroked.

**So I commented out the fill & stroke here**

```
    var yNode = svg.append("g")
        //.style("fill", "none")
        //.style("stroke", "#000")               
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + left + ",0)")
        //.attr("class", "axis")
        .call(yAxis);
```

**Selected the path and added the fill and stroke styles**

```
    yNode.select('path')
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "#000");
```